# Express route works fine, until it calls separate function, crashes server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

The first GET request, `(/not-work)`, calls a separate function, `database()`, with some code to connect to a database and return data. This successfully runs the `database()` function and that function returns data, but `const result`, does not get that data properly returned. Instead an unfufilled database connection object is returned. The second request however, `(/works)`, runs nearly the exact same code as, just within the GET route itself. This works perfectly. I cannot for the life of me understand why.

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const sql = require('mssql')
const sqlConfig = {
    user: 'login',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'database',
    server: '123.456.789.012'
}

const database = () => {
    return sql.connect(sqlConfig,
        (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            try {
                return new sql.Request()
                    .execute('dbo.SQLProcedure', (err, recordset) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err)
                        return recordset;
                    });
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
}

app.get('/not-work', (req, res) => {
    const result = database();
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});

app.get('/works', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig,
        (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            try {
                new sql.Request()
                    .execute('dbo.SQLProcedure', (err, recordset) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err)
                        res.send(recordset);
                    });
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.send(err);
            }
        });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(888, () => {
    console.log('Server listening 888');
});
```

Comment: Your `database()` function is just returning the value of `sql.connect()`.  The other return statements are just returning from asynchronous callbacks which don't have anything to do with the higher level return value.

Comment: See [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for advice on how to get your asynchronous result back from your `database()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

you must use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
const database = async () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig,
      (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err); // or reject(err)
        try {
          new sql.Request()
            .execute('dbo.SQLProcedure', (err, recordset) => {
              if (err) console.log(err) // or reject(err)
              return resolve(recordset);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err) // or reject(err)
        }
      });
  })
}
```

```
app.get('/not-work', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await database();
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: I've used async/await all throughout the code in many different ways with no success, including your example here. In addition, the working code does not require any async/await and returns the data just fine. I appreciate you looking into it though!

Comment: i updated the answer, you can use `Promise`

Comment: you don't need async await in your working code because your chaining the callbacks

Comment: adding a Promise just stalls the function, and the returned data still never makes it back to the GET request